# what is the data type of the parameter passed to saltarelle's jquery ajax callback

Tags: c#, jquery

```
 var jqopt = new jQueryAjaxOptions
            {
                Url = Model.Helper.ServiceEndpoint,
                Type = "Get"
            };

 var req = jQuery.Ajax(jqopt);
            req.Success(_ => { Log("Ajax succeeded: " + _.ToString()); });
            req.Fail(_ => { Log("Calling back after failure!!" + _.ToString()); });
```

I need to see the error message instead of object _ in the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the signatures for the success and error callbacks

```
  private void jsSuccessCallBack(object data, string textStatus, jQueryXmlHttpRequest request)
        {

            var items = data as List<FamilyTrustBE>;
            foreach (FamilyTrustBE item in items)
            {
                Helper.Log(string.Format("Result is: id {0}, {1}: {2}", item.id, item.name, item.description));
            }

        }

        private void jsErrorCallBack(jQueryXmlHttpRequest request, string textStatus, Exception error)
        {
            dynamic myerr = error;
            Helper.Log(string.Format("status={0} in ERROR callback. Error: {1}, Inner: {2}", textStatus, myerr.message, myerr.InnerException));
        }
```

Here's my Helper.Log method:

```
    [IgnoreNamespace]
internal class Helper
{ 
    public static void Log(string str)
    {
        var content = jQuery.Select(Helper.HTMLMessageDivSelector).GetHtml();
        var messageDiv = jQuery.Select(Helper.HTMLMessageDivSelector);
        messageDiv.Html(str + "<br/>" + content);

        //write message to debug console if it is defined
        dynamic w = System.Html.Window.Self;
        { 
                if (w.console is object)   
                    w.console.log(str);
        }

    }
 }
```